# Simple T Test of difference of means

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Suppose I have the following data:
$$\bar x_1=15$$
$$\bar x_2=12.5$$
$$\sigma_1=1.8$$
$$\sigma_2=1.75$$
$$n_1=800$$
$$n_2=3000$$
And I want to test:
$$H_0:\mu_1-\mu_2>0$$
$$H_a:\mu_1-\mu_2<0$$

Lets say at a 0.05 level.  So I find SE:
$$SE^2=\frac{\sigma_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{\sigma_2^2}{n_2}$$
This gives SE = 0.07
So I calculate my t stat:
$$t=\frac{\bar x_1-\bar x_2}{SE}=35$$
So my p-value is 0.  This means I reject my null hypothesis, as the corresponding p value ~0.

I want to make sure I am doing this right, because with these numbers, I would expect that we would fail to reject the null because x1 will be much greater than x2.  Is my analysis of this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are correct. Consider that the high level of significance in this case mostly depends on the relatively large  sizes of the two groups.

Comment: So does this mean I reject Ho or fail to reject it?

Comment: The calculations that you made (I assume you performed a one-tail test) actually tested the null hypothesis $H_0:\mu_1-\mu_2 \leq 0$ and the alternative hypothesis $H_a:\mu_1-\mu_2>0$ (note that they are switched in comparison with those you stated at the beginning if the OP). So, they confirm that the alternative hypothesis $H_a:\mu_1-\mu_2>0$ is probably true, and the null hypothesis has to be rejected.